# Java scanner: nextInt

Tags: java

I am a beginner in programming (learning Java). I am trying to write a program in which I list four different options for the user to choose from.

Here is part of it:

```
import java.util.*;
    public class fight {

            public static int upgrade1 = 0;
            public static int upgrade2 = 0;
            public static int upgrade3 = 0;
            public static int upgrade4 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your name:");

            String player = scan.next();    

System.out.println("You have earned 2 upgrade points. Which of the following traits would you like to boost by 2 points?\n"
    + " 1. upgrade1\n 2. upgrade2\n 3. upgrade3\n"
    + " 4. upgrade4");

                    if (scan.nextInt() == 1) {
                        upgrade1 = upgrade1 + 2;
                            System.out.println("Your upgrade1 level is now: " + upgrade1);
                    }
                    else if (scan.nextInt() == 2) {
                        upgrade2 = upgrade2 + 2;
                            System.out.println("Your upgrade2 level is now: " + upgrade2);
                    }
                    else if (scan.nextInt() == 3) {
                        upgrade3 = upgrade3 + 2;
                            System.out.println("Your upgrade3 level is now: " + upgrade3);
                    }
                    else if (scan.nextInt() == 4) {
                        upgrade4 = upgrade4 + 2;
                            System.out.println("Your upgrade4 level is now: " + upgrade4);
                    }                                                       
        }
}
```

The problem is: When the user enters which option they want to pick, they must enter the number (x being the number they choose) x amount of times. For instance, the user wants to choose option 3. They must enter the number 3 three times into the console before it understands and completes the next line.

Here is the console after running the program:

Please enter your name:
rick
Hello, rick. You have earned 2 upgrade points. Which of the following traits would you like to boost by 2 points?
 1. upgrade1
 2. upgrade2
 3. upgrade3
 4. upgrade4
3
3
3
Your upgrade3 level is now: 2

I hope this makes sense, and any help is much appreciated (I assume I'm just making a dumb rookie error). Also, if you have any constructive criticism about the way it's structured, please don't hesitate. Thanks!

Comment: You're calling scan.nextInt X amount of times as well.  Did you notice that? :D

Comment: Yes, like Wug hinted, call scan.nextInt() once and store the result in a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean! :\

Comment: Ok, I see what you all mean. If I were to add another section that was basically the same as this afterwards, wouldn't the int 'choice' stay equal to 1, making all the choices in the rest of the program equal to 1? Would I need to make 'choice' static so it could change with each choice made in the program? A little extra help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are calling scan.nextInt() in every if/else if statement. What you want to do is store the value they entered and then check the value in the if/else if statements, otherwise you're basically prompting the user for input multiple times.

```
int input = scan.nextInt();

if (input == 1) {
    upgrade1 = upgrade1 + 2;
        System.out.println("Your upgrade1 level is now: " + upgrade1);
}
else if (input == 2) {
    upgrade2 = upgrade2 + 2;
        System.out.println("Your upgrade2 level is now: " + upgrade2);
}
else if (input == 3) {
    upgrade3 = upgrade3 + 2;
        System.out.println("Your upgrade3 level is now: " + upgrade3);
}
else if (input == 4) {
    upgrade4 = upgrade4 + 2;
        System.out.println("Your upgrade4 level is now: " + upgrade4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't repeatedly call scan.nextInt().  Unless, of course, you're expecting *multiple* different integers to be read.

Instead:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
String player = scan.next();
int ichoice = scan.nextInt();
switch (ichoice) {
  case 1:
  ...
```

Comment: Oooh, a switch statement! fancy.  However, seeing as we're dealing with a rookie here, it would probably be a good idea to write out the whole thing since he may not have seen the syntax before.

Comment: If he will use `switch()` he can use nextInt() because switch calls it only once...

Comment: The problem is I'm not entirely sure how to set up a switch past what he wrote :\ I could probably figure it out pretty easily though, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `scan.nextInt` in one of your if statements, it reads another int.  Change to:

```
int userChoice = scan.nextInt();
if (userChoice == 1)
{
    ...
}
else if (userChoice == 2)

...
```

As for constructive criticism, pick a style you like and use it.  Your indentation is all over the place; this makes code more difficult to read.  It doesn't matter if it's a commonly used style and it doesn't matter what everyone else thinks of it, just make sure *you* like it and stick to it.

Eclipse can auto-format code for you, and this behavior is customizable (You can fiddle with it so it matches your style).

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `nextInt()`, another int is read from the input. You thus want to call it only once!

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();

if (choice == 1) ...
if (choice == 2) ...
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you all mean. If I were to add another section that was basically the same as this afterwards, wouldn't the int 'choice' stay equal to 1, making all the choices in the rest of the program equal to 1? Would I need to make 'choice' static so it could change with each choice made in the program? A little extra help would be much appreciated :)